# What is a function with a class type called in C++?

Tags: c++, class

I've been searching across the web but seen to not find the keyword. let's say I want to use the class type to create a method/function. Here is an easy example:

```
struct action{
//constructor
action(int n){
}
};
action move(){
}
```

here, I'm using the `action` class as the type of the function. Here are my questions: What is this called? How do I use the constructor of the class? what should I return in the function move? (it doesn't let me return `this`. error:`[invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function]`)

Comment: Your `move` function looks like a normal non-member function, with `action` as the return type. And as a non-member function it of course can't use `this` since it's not member of any object that `this` can point to.

Comment: It's just a function. Theres nothing special about it. Your error suggests that you used `this` in `move()` which is outside the class. So its a standalone function. Its not a method, and so `this` doesn't make sense.

Comment: And it seems to me that you could use [a couple of good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read.

Comment: Edited the code to include an `int` argument for the constructor. See OPs comments below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is this called?

`move` is the name of a free function. The full signature `action move()` tells you that its return value is an instance of type `action` and that the functions doesn't expect any parameters. Note that free functions are different from *member functions* in that they don't have a special relationship to any class.

> How do I use the constructor of the class?

The constructor is called when you create an instance of that class. Example:

```
action instance; // calls default constructor
```

Note that you don't really invoke constructors directly. In the above case, it's a declaration that leads to a call to `action::action()`.

> what should I return in the function move?

An instance of `action`, because the function signature says so:

```
action move() { return action{}; }
```

---

If your constructor takes parameters, here's an adjusted example:

```
struct action {
    action(int n) { /* do stuff with the argument... */ }
};

action move() { return action{42}; }
```

Comment: can you give me an example of how to use the constructor? say the constructor takes in an int

Comment: Im sorry but im very new to this... i thought `action move` is an object of the class `action`. If so, why can't it "return itself" as an object?

Comment: @EdenCheung Because you declared it **outside** of the action class. Put it inside if you want it to be a memory function.

Comment: @EdenCheung It helps to understand these things if you indent your code poperly. With proper indentation you would easily see that `move` is outside of the `action` class.

Comment: I cannot really wrap my head around this. Let me tell you what i originally want this to do. So in the class `action`, i have some variables and some member functions. I want to create objects like move etc. and i need to access the member objects and methods in the action class.

Comment: The way you have written the code above `move` is a function not an object. Really does sound like you need to read a good C++ book. C++ is difficult, you can't guess.

Comment: I do have the book "The C++ Programing Languge". Need to swallow the book over and over ;)

Comment: @EdenCheung You mean Stroupstrup's book? That's not a book for beginners. I would look at the list linked to in the comments above.

Comment: i do understand his book, but i did not read it from start to end

Comment: Let me try to explain what my problem actually is. First, what is the difference between `action move(){}` and `action move{}`? I know its a function and an object, but does the function need a constructor?

Comment: @EdenCheung No functions don't need constructors because they aren't objects, they just need to be defined. (though there are various function-like objects in C++, but regular functions are not objects)

Comment: Is it possible to use the constructor in a function?

Comment: Now i understand. So functions have different properties than objects.

Answer (score 2):

There's no special name for this situation. It's perfectly common.

You call the constructor in all the usual ways, e.g

```
action move() {
    return action(42);
}
```

or

```
action move() {
    action a(42);
    return a;
}
```

In your code (and my answer) `move` is a normal function. Maybe you meant it to be a member function, in which case you could also `return *this;` to return the current object.